# How can I get a list of indices of values related to each other by lineage? [R]

Tags: r, relationship, matching

suppose I have a dataframe where there are two columns that indicate a direct relationship between the parallel values.

```
c2 <- c(2,5,7,8,10)
c1 <- c(1,3,2,7,5)
df <- data.frame(c1, c2)
```

Such that:

1 is related to 2 `[1]`,
2 is related to 7 `[3]`,
7 is related to 8 `[4]`

So I get a vector of the indexes 1,3, and 4

and then 3 is related to 5 `[2]`,
and 5 is related to 10 `[5]`

so I get a vector of the indexes 2 and 5?

It hurts my brain.

Answer (score 2):

This could be effectively solved using the `igraph` library:

```
common_ids <- clusters(graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE))$membership
split(1:nrow(df), common_ids[match(df$c1, names(common_ids))])

$`1`
[1] 1 3 4

$`2`
[1] 2 5
```

If also members of the groups are of interest:

```
split(names(common_ids), common_ids)

$`1`
[1] "1" "2" "7" "8"

$`2`
[1] "3"  "5"  "10"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have had experience with graph previously, but I was wondering if there was a simpler base solution using value matching.

Comment: It could be solved using some joins, but with larger datasets, that might be increasingly ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `igraph`

```
lapply(
  groups(components(graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE))),
  function(x) Filter(Negate(is.na),match(x, as.character(df$c1)))
)
```

gives

```
$`1`
[1] 1 3 4

$`2`
[1] 2 5
```